# Gradle Could not find method “() for arguments

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I have just install android studio and import a project. but when i run it could not find method error will come. I am new in android studio please any one help.
I have android studio version is 2.2.3

my gradle file which has error is

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
  }
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
  }
}
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
}
dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered many times but anyway...

**What is Gradle?**

*Gradle is software for building software, otherwise known as “build automation
software” or “build systems”. But build system does not compile, link, package, etc. applications
directly, but instead directs separate compilers, linkers, and packagers to do that
work.*

Android studio usually has two gradle files:

**The Project-Level File** which controls the Gradle configuration for
all modules in your project.

**The Module-Level Gradle File** which contains unique settings
for this module, independent of any other module that your project may have in the
future.

For more information you can refer to the The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development book or any other relevant book about android development in Android Studio

**Probably your android declaration is in Project-level build gradle but instead it should be in module-level gradle.**

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** use the `android` block in the **top level** file.

You have to add it in the `root/app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    //.....
}
```